# python, collecting links / script values from page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, mechanize, python-requests

I am trying to make a program to collect links and some values from a website. It works mostly well but I have come across a page in which it does not work.

With firebug I can see that this is the html code of the illusive "link" (cant find it when viewing the pages source thou):

```
<a class="visit" href="/tet?id=12&mv=13&san=221">

    221

</a>
```

and this is the script:

```
<td><a href=\"/tet?id=12&mv=13&san=221\" class=\"visit\">221<\/a><\/td><\/tr>
```

I'm wondering how to get either the "link" ("/tet?id=12&mv=13&san=221") from the html code and the string "221" from either the script or the html using selenium, mechanize or requests (or some other library)

I have made an unsuccessful attempt at getting it with mechanize using the br.links() function, which collected a number of links from the side, just not the one i am after

extra info: This might be important. to get to the page I have to click on a button with this code:

```
<a id="f33" class="button-flat small selected-no" onclick="qc.pA('visitform', 'f33', 'QClickEvent', '', 'f52'); if ($j('#f44').length == 0) { $j('f44').style.display='inline'; }; $j('#f38').hide();qc.recordControlModification('f38', 'DisplayStyle', 'hide'); document.getElementById('forumpanel').className = 'section-3'; return false;" href="#">

    load2

</a>
```

after which a "new page" loads in a part of the window (but the url never changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pasted the wrong script of yours ;)

I'm not sure what you need exactly - there are at least two different approaches.

- Matching all hrefs using regex
- Matching specific tags and using getAttribute(...)

For the first one, you have to get the whole html source of the page with something like `webdriver.page_source` and using something like the following regex (you will have to escape either the normal or the double quotes!):

```
<a.+?href=['"](.*?)['"].*?/?>
```

If you need the hrefs of all matching links, you could use something similar to `webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.visit')` (take care to choose `find_elements_...` instead of `find_element_...`!) to obtain a list of webelements and iterate through them to get their attributes.

This could result in code like this:

```
hrefs = []
elements = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.visit')

for element in elements:
    hrefs.append(element.getAttribute('href'))
```

Or a one liner using list comprehension:

```
hrefs = [element.getAttribute('href') for element \
         in webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.visit')]
```

Comment: sry, you're right. I did miss part of the script code lol.... I will try those approaches out and get back with the results, thanks

Comment: is there any way of making "webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector(".visit").get_attribute("href")" find all such links, not just the first? if so it would be a great solution to this problem

Comment: @user3053161 I've edited my answer - I hope it's okay! I haven't tried it and my last Python adventures were a few months ago; so please notify my about syntax errors or feel free to correct my answer by yourself :)